# Keycloak Roles Synchronization Event Listener

Tags: jboss, synchronization, roles, keycloak

I'm new with keycloak and i'm facing up to the federation provider implementation.

As yet I'm able to synchronize the keycloak database with my user repository by adding a new user at log-in time.

I'm now fighting with groups/roles. When should i have to synghronize roles? A login time too?

Is there an entry point to catch, in the provider interfaces implementation,by which i could directly add all my user groups?
What is the standard procedure for doing this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you figure it out? In Keycloak docs I can find Group/Role Mappers for LDAP https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-adminstration-guide/content/topics/user-federation/ldap.html
I'm still interested if you were successful with you solution.